# Convert array to string javascript by removing commas

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

I have an array A such that

```
A = [ '6', '6', '.', '5' ]
```

I wish to convert it into a string, such that when I console.log A, it simply returns 66.5,
ie

```
console.log(A) 
//expected Output
 66.5
```

currently, the output I am getting is

```
[ '6', '6', '.', '5' ]
```

When I do a to string, ie  `console.log(A.toString());` , it is giving the output `6,6,.,5,`

When I try to replace "," with "", ie  `console.log("A = "+A.toString().replace(",", ""))` , it is giving the output `A = 66,.,5`

How do I make it so that it gives the output `A=66.5`

Comment: Use join: `A.join('')`

Answer (score 11):

You can simple use the `Array.prototype.join` function

```js
const A = [ '6', '6', '.', '5' ];

console.log(A.join(''));
```

As explain on the Documentation page of [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

> The **join()** method creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array (or an array-like object), separated by commas or a specified separator string. If the array has only one item, then that item will be returned without using the separator.

It can take as parameter the **separator** which will be use to separate element from the array when they are joined.

```
let list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

list.join("-"); // will return "a-b-c-d"
list.join("/"); // will return "a/b/c/d"
list.join(""); // will return "abcd"
```

By default the separator is **,**. This means if you don't specify which character will be use as the separator it will use the `,` character

```
list.join(); // will return a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
console.log(['6', '6', '.', '5'].join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parseFloat([ '6', '6', '.', '5' ].toString().split(',').join(""))
```

Comment: [ '6', '6', '.', '5' ].join('') will work not need to any additional operation.

Comment: We are looking at different options here